# I want only date but as Timestamp , to query data on CREATE_TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, ptc-windchill

I am querying date using QuerySpec on the basis of `CREATE_TIMESTAMP` ,following is my piece of code, compiler says `CREATE_TIMESTAMP` is a `Timestamp` ,whereas `day` is String . I have tried many work around but didn't workout

```
Date date=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String day=format.format(date);
qs.appendWhere(new SearchCondition(QueueEntry.class,
                                   QueueEntry.CREATE_TIMESTAMP,
                                   SearchCondition.LIKE,day), 
                                   new int[] {0,1});
```

Comment: Why don't you use a TimeStamp? Also: why are you using `SearchCondition.LIKE` instead of `SearchCondition.EQUALS`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I actual wanted to query entries, filtering it just by date , which isnt possible with timestamp, so i used java api instead to WC api ,wrote quey itself ...altered the session and got what i want ,  thanks for replying man